Nexus OSS Docker repository binds to localhost only
We have installed a Nexus OSS 3 on CentOS 7 linux host. We have configured a Docker repository listening to port 8084. We cannot reach the new docker registry remotely because port 8084 is bound to the localhost (127.0.0.1). How do we configure Nexus OSS to bind port 8084 to any IP address (0.0.0.0) so we can connect to the docker repository remotely?
Here is a partial list of what ports are bound:
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8081          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24380/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24380/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8083          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24380/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8084          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24380/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14465/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1545/master
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      14465/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1545/master
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      2634/httpd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2634/httpd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           635/rpcbind
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                635/rpcbind
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                665/chronyd
udp6       0      0 :::804                  :::*                                635/rpcbind

We are running Apache2 to forward HTTP on port 80 to 8081.
Can Apache2 be used to reverse proxy port 8084? If so, what would that configuration look like?
